# Execute Powershell containing Sharepoint commands on remote server, from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, kerberos

Straight to the point:

I'm working on a service that is supposed to run on Sharepoint server.
The service should be able to run a Powershell script locally and also run the same script on an array of Sharepoint servers in the same domain.
The service runs as a user who is admin on the local server AND the remote servers.

The powershell script contains the following:

```
Try{
   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
   Install-SPInfoPathFormTemplate -Path someInfoPath.xsn
}
Catch
{
    Add-Content C:\Temp\log.txt "$($_.Exception)" 
}
```

I have tried using the Powershell class in C# to invoke the script like this:

```
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo();
connectionInfo.ComputerName = machineAddress;
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{ 
    ps.Runspace = runspace;
    ps.AddScript("Invoke-Expression C:\Temp\PowershellTest.ps1"); 
    var results = ps.Invoke();
    Console.WriteLine(results);
}  
runspace.Close();
```

This fails without returning any error to my C# program but in the log.txt file I can see this error: ....The Term Install-SPInfoPathFormTemplate is not a known cmdlet....

This tell me that the Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell command is not successfull.

So I tried to call the Powershell via a Process.Start() from C# like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "Invoke-Command -ComputerName \\machineName -Path C:\Temp\PowershellTest.ps1

   using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
   {
        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
   }
```

However the result is the same.

If I try to run the powershell script manually while logged on to a remote desktop it executes perfectly or returns an error, if I make an error on purpose.

I suspect a Kerberos Double-Hop problem.

To the question:
 1. Is it possible to run SharePoint InfoPath Services cmdlets (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee906553.aspx) remotely at all?
 2. Could this be a Double-Hop problem and if so, how can I get around it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there where multiple errors in the technical setup of this solution.

First: The service was running from IIS and in the advanced properties of the app pool the setting "Load user profile" was set to false. When this was set to true, the powershell was run successfully.

Second: In order to being able to call the powershell on the remote machine and avoid the Double-Hop problem, I had to use PSExec and include the credentials. (Of course passing the credentials meant I had to encrypt the config file since they were stored there)

Last but not least: The user that the app pool was running under did not have the appropiate amount of privileges. This was VERY hard to debug because there PSExec returned a message saying: "Powershell exited with error code 0" but from the log I put in the powershell, I could see that the powershell was not executed.

Most of the solution to this problem was of a technical nature but still I think it was relevant to share the outcome with you.